# No default constructor available

Tags: java, android, oop

I have a parent class :

```
public class Partida {

    private ArrayList<Jugador> jugadores;
    private Tablero tablero;
    private ArrayList<PartidaListener> observadores;        
    
    public Partida(Tablero tablero, ArrayList<Jugador> jugadores) {
        observadores = new ArrayList<>();
        this.tablero = tablero;
        this.jugadores = jugadores;
    }
```

That is inherited by the following class:

```
public class PartidaC4 extends Partida {

    private ArrayList<JugadorC4> jugadores;
    private TableroC4 tablero;
    private ArrayList<PartidaListenerC4> observadores;

    public PartidaC4(TableroC4 tablero, ArrayList<JugadorC4> jugadores) {
        observadores = new ArrayList<>();
        this.tablero = tablero;
        this.jugadores = jugadores;
    }
```

When writing this, I get the error

> Error:(39, 73) error: constructor Partida in class Partida cannot be applied to given types;
>
> required: Tablero,ArrayList found: no arguments
>
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I think it's very basic but I can't find a solution. I tried to use both solutions provided by Android Studio (using `super()`) but I'm not happy with this solution, because I need to use different objects types than the ones from the parent class.

What should I do?

Comment: What line is the error coming from? Please add the error log to your question

Comment: the error come from the line where i declare the PartidaC4 constructor

Comment: Can you paste the error log please? And what is the difference between all of your classes that end with "C4" and the ones that don't end with "C4"?

Comment: the "C4" classes are children of the regular classes; "tableroC4" is a children of "tablero" and so on. For the error, AndroidStudio underlines my PartidaC4 with the error i mentioned; compiling anyway just fails with : Error:(39, 73) error: constructor Partida in class Partida cannot be applied to given types;
required: Tablero,ArrayList<Jugador>
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define any arguments you need for your constructor, but it is necessary to call one constructor of the super class as the first line of your own constructor. This can be done using super() or super(arguments).

```
public class PartidaC4 extends Partida  {

    public PartidaC4() {
        super(tablero,jugadores);
        //do whatever you want to do in your constructor here
    }

    public PartidaC4(TableroC4 tablero, ArrayList<JugadorC4> jugadores) {
        super(tablero, jugadores);
        //do whatever you want to do in your constructor here
    }

}
```

Comment: if i add "super(tablero, jugadores);" i get : "Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'JugadorC4', requiered 'Jugador'"

Comment: you need an arrayList of type  Jugador to pass it with super keyword

Comment: change this arraylist (ArrayList<JugadorC4> jugadores) into (ArrayList<Jugador> jugadores) in class PartidaC4..  this will work .

Answer (score 2):

`PartidaC4` class is a subclass of `Partida` so when instanciating a `PartidaC4` you need to specify how its `Partida` part should be initialized. As you didn't say anything about this Java tried to initialize the `Partida` part using a construtor with no arguments, but there is no in `Partida` class. So the error.
We don't really know what you need but it looks like you want to initialize this way:

```
public Partida(Tablero tablero, ArrayList<Jugador> jugadores) {
    super(tablero, jugadores): // initialize the "super" part with appropriate arguments.
    observadores = new ArrayList<>();
    this.tablero = tablero;
    this.jugadores = jugadores;
}
```

As already mentioned, you should be aware that there is redundancy in your definitions: a `PartidaC4` has `tablero`, `jugadores` and `observadores` defined in it plus `tablero`, `jugadores` and `observadores` inherited from the super class. I doubt it is what you want...

Comment: I see what you mean, but using this constructor i can't use my C4 right ? Plus i also need the fields again because they were private in parent, and thus not inherited right ?

Comment: Make them protected or give protected accessors. Being private doesn't mean not inherited but inherited and not accessible. Protected mean inherited and accessible from the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Either your base Partida class needs a no argument constructor, or your PartidaC4 class needs to call a constructor of it in its constructor using super().  Most likely you want the second, since you haven't already defined a no args constructor.

Also, your code smells a bit.  You shouldn't be constructing the same variables in both the base and the parent class.  One of the two should be defining these, not both.

Comment: do you mean something like : public PartidaC4(Tablero tablero, ArrayList<Jugador> jugadores) {
        super(tablero, jugadores);
    } ? Because i tried, but with this i can't pass my "C4" objects, which are children of the normal object the parent constructor takes normally